# React useState not updating mapped content

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-state

I feel like im missing something that is staring me right in the face. I am trying to have content stored in an array of objects update when a checkbox is on or off. The console log is showing the object data is updating correctly so I assume my fault resides in not understanding useState fully?

```
const [statistics, setStatistics] = useState([
    {
        id: 1,
        content: <div>Content1</div>,
        state: true,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        content: <div>Content2</div>,
        state: true,
    },
]);
```

In the component:

```
{statistics.map((item) => (item.state ? item.content : <></>))}

<input
type="checkbox"
    onChange={(e) => {
        let newArr = statistics;
        e.target.checked
            ? (newArr[0].state = true)
            : (newArr[0].state = false);
        setStatistics(newArr);
        console.log(statistics);
    }}
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to change the state directly, instead you need to work with a copy of the state and make all changes to it.

Just replace in your code this string:

`let newArr = statistics; // as link to base array`

to

`let newArr = [...statistics]; // as new copy of base array`

and it will works.
React skips all state changes if they are made directly.

Answer (score 0):

To create a new array as copy/clone of another array, in ES6, we can use the spread operator. You can not use `=` here, since it will only copy the reference to the original array and not create a new variable. Just read [here](https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/35-es6-way-to-clone-an-array/#why-can-t-i-use-to-copy-an-array) for reference.

In your case, your **newArray** will refer to the old **statistics** and will not be detected as the new state. That is why no re-render takes place after you made changes to it.

So here, you can do this:

```
  return (
    <>
      {statistics.map((item) => (item.state ? item.content : <></>))}
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        onChange={(e) => {
          setStatistics((prevStats) => {
            const newStats = [...prevStats];
            e.target.checked
              ? (newStats[0].state = true)
              : (newStats[0].state = false);
            return newStats;
          });
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
```